# Can't pinpoint the cause of a 'Null Pointer Exception' in Java

Tags: java, xml, data-structures

Okay, I've been trying to fix this for the past week or so, and I usually don't like asking this type of question on here, but I don't really have a choice at this point.

I'm very new to Java, which I'm sure is the reason for this in the first place.

Well, what I'm trying to do here is to read an XML file with "WBS" (work breakdown structure) nodes and "Activity" nodes, and put them in this data structure for later use. I have a class called `WBS`, which essentially consists of an ArrayList of children `WBS` objects, and another ArrayList of `Activity` objects (another little class). Now here's the problem: I can get all the "WBS" nodes from the XML file, I can get the "Activity" nodes, but when I try getting *both* of them in sequence, I get the aforementioned "Null Pointer Exception". I'm posting all of the code, since, it's in a number of different files, and quite frankly is not really relevant. However, if you think it would help, I can edit it in.

If either of the `Problem` lines are edited out, everything works (minus the functionality of the line taken out)

Here's the problematic code:

```
   private WBS getWBSStructure(Element initElement){
      WBS structure = new WBS();
      structure.setName(initElement.getElementsByTagName("Name").
            item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
      //WBSElement = initElement;
      structure.Children = new ArrayList<WBS>();
      NodeList initAllChildren = initElement.getChildNodes();
      for(int n=0;n<initAllChildren.getLength();n++){
         Node Child = initAllChildren.item(n);
         String childName = Child.getNodeName();
         if(childName=="WBS") {
           structure.Children.add(getWBSStructure((Element)Child));//<--Problem 1
           continue;
         }
         if(childName=="Activity") {
           structure.Activities.add(getActivity((Element)Child));//<--Problem 2
           continue;
         }
      }
      return structure;
   }

   private Activity getActivity(Element initElement){
      Activity act = new Activity();
      act.setName(initElement.getElementsByTagName("Name").
            item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
      act.OriginalDuration = Integer.parseInt(initElement.
            getElementsByTagName("PlannedDuration").item(0).
            getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
      return act;
   }
```

Comments requstion stack trace. Is this adequate?

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at analyzer_main.PriXMLReader.getWBSStructure(PriXMLReader.java:84)
    at analyzer_main.PriXMLReader.getWBSStructure(PriXMLReader.java:83)
    at analyzer_main.PriXMLReader.getWBSStructure(PriXMLReader.java:60)
    at analyzer_main.main_window$1.shellActivated(main_window.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.WM_ACTIVATE(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.WM_ACTIVATE(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.BringWindowToTop(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.bringToTop(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.open(Unknown Source)
    at analyzer_main.main_window.open(main_window.java:60)
    at analyzer_main.main_window.main(main_window.java:45)

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: Yes. Maybe that didn't work because of my lack of any Java knowledge, but yeah I'll continue trying that,

Comment: @Matt Ball: I actually do not know how to do that. Is that bad?

Comment: How do I do that in Eclipse? Sorry for the ignorance. edit: nvm I think I might have just posted it...

Comment: What is on line 84 of PriXMLReader.java?

Comment: Sorry, for the ambiguity... line 84 is `Problem 2` in the code posted.

Comment: Don't compare Strings with ==, but rather use equals. For example, don't do this: `if(childName=="Activity"){`, but instead do this: `if(childName.equals("Activity")) {`. Also, why not do a println at your problem 2 line to see which object is null. Also, you really should format that code so that it is readable, especially if you want unpaid volunteers (us!) to help you. Sorry, but it is attrocious.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: Thanks for your response. I'll change that if it's better, I'm used to C and C++.

Comment: In fact I tried to format the code a little better for you. Please be sure that the problem 1 and problem 2 are on the correct lines.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: They are, I'm sure. I'm getting the line number from Eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line should give Null pointer exception every time you run this code. No matter if you edited a line before or not.

```
if (childName=="Activity") {
    structure.Activities.add(getActivity((Element)Child));
    continue;
```

You didn't initialize `structure.Activities` at all. There should have been something like:

```
structure.Activities = new ArrayList<Activity>();
```

Comment: Yes that worked like a charm!! Thank you kindly! I have to wait a minute, but I'll then accept your answer.